# How to integrate this ODE?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE:
$$ y'(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-x+y}{2x+y}}. $$

I tried to transform it to a homogeneous differential equation, I found
$$ s'(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{s-1}{s+2}}-s$$ where $$ s(x) = \frac{2y(x)+3}{2x-1}.$$
Next? I don't know.

Comment: This equation is separable, so your only problem is solving the integral $$\int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{\frac{s-1}{s+2}}-s} = x $$

Comment: @Dylan, Thanks. And how to do that? Is there an easier method to solve the EDO without the need to calculate the above integral?

Comment: Unfortunately, the integral is non-elementary, so there's no easy answer. You can try numerical methods